# calling a function inside a function that uses prototype property

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I am creating this Node...

```
function Node ( name, level, parent ) {
  this.name = name;
  this.level = level;
  this.children = [];
  this.parent = parent;
  this.id = this.createId();
}
```

When I reference `this.name`, `this.level`, `this.parent`, and `this.children` everything works great in the function I made.  When I try and reference `this.id` I get nothing.

This is my function for setting `this.id`...

```
Node.prototype.createId = function () {
  var p = this.parent;
  return p.name;
}
```

I don't know if Im calling it correctly in the Node function.

Comment: Could you show how you are calling it?

Comment: How are you creating the Node? Are you sure that `parent` is not `undefined`? - If it is undefined, you'll get a script error when you reference `p.name`.

Comment: Also, why the `createId()` method to begin with? Why not simply set `this.id = parent.name` in your constructor?

Comment: @Alberto Zaccagni I am calling is right in the Node Function

Comment: As others have alluded to, it seems as though the issue is likely in the way you're trying to use this code. Here's a [slightly modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/CvkWL/) that works.

Comment: @Marlon Bernardes I have manually set a root node so there is always a parent

Comment: @AndreDion this is just a simple example I am going to be doing something more complicated, and yes I have set my root node like you did

Comment: If the code you've provided isn't relevant to your issue, then what kind of help are you hoping to get?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pass `this` keyword as parameter in `this.createId();` like following

```
function Node ( name, level, parent ) {
            this.name = name;
            this.level = level;
            this.children = [];
            this.parent = parent;
            this.id = this.createId(this);
        }
```

then in node do this

```
Node.prototype.createId = function (self)
        {
            var p = self.parent;
            return p.name;
        }
```

Comment: `this` inside `Node.prototype.createId()` refers to the same object as `self`, thus `self` is totally redundant.